# Event Emitter is not working inside Event listener

Tags: angular, openlayers-6

I work with Angular and OpenLayers. When angular button is clicked I call function (inside service) which does following:

```
this.draw.on('drawend', function(event) {
  this.drawEvent.next([this.feature, this.featureLayer]);
});
```

drawEvent should call component, but nothing happens.
When I emit drawEvent outside this.draw.on it works fine.

Does it have something with NgZone? I am beginner with Angular and any kind of tip would be helpful.

Comment: try calling `cdRef.markForCheck()` after `.next` where cdRef is ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: could be related to `this` being out of scope? try debugging and see what is happening.

Comment: I also think this might be related to `this` being out of scope. Have you tried to use use an arrow function ?

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! This was out of the scope and arrow function fixed the problem!